# Shiny app in web browser fails to load - (192.***.2.** took too long to respond)

Tags: r, shiny, self-hosting

I am trying to host a `shiny` application from my PC for my team. I am currently using the following code to set my PC as the server:

```
runApp(app, host = '192.***.2.**', port = 4444, launch.browser = T)
```

where `app` is the shinyApp object. I shared the host address and port with my teammates. While the app works fine on my system, it fails to load in the browser of other PCs with this message :"took too long to respond". OS of my PC is Windows 10 and available RAM is 8gb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RShiny - How to share app within network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897010/rshiny-how-to-share-app-within-network)

Comment: I want to host the app from a dedicated local server within the company, which the OP of that question tried to do, but my colleagues get the above mentioned error. And there was no answer marked as correct by that OP.

Comment: Please have a look on the link to evaluate the different ways to share an application. `runApp` is just local to your computer from what I know.